# Making reference to the key name of parent in a YAML file?

Tags: node.js, yaml, serverless-framework

Is it possible to reference the name of a parent key in a YAML file?

For example, if I have the following YAML structure:

```
properties:
   ServicecA:
      storage: 100
   ServicecB:
      storage: 200

MyConfiguration:
   ServiceA:
      storage: ${self:properties.ServicecA.storage}
   ServiceB:
      storage: ${self:properties.ServiceB.storage}
```

I'm not too happy that I have to type `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` again in the `storage` value. I was wondering if I could actually reference that portion as a variable which has the name of its parent key. Something like this:

```
properties:
   ServicecA:
      storage: 100
   ServicecB:
      storage: 200

MyConfiguration:
   ServiceA:
      storage: ${self:properties.${parent:keyName}.storage}
   ServiceB:
      storage: ${self:properties.${parent:keyName}.storage}
```

And the `${parent:keyName}` should refer to the key name of its parent.

Would this be possible in a regular YAML file?

Comment: `${self:properties.ServiceA.storage}` in YAML is simply a scalar that would be loaded as string. It doesn't reference anything. You are probably using some library or application that assigns a different meaning to it, but without telling us which one it is, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality would require the ability to inspect the current path in the structure. Moreover, it would require string manipulation since the source key is `ServiceA` but the target key is `ServicecA`.

[The docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) mention neither the ability to inspect the current path nor any functionality to insert that `c` into a given string. So it seems to be very much not possible to do.